# https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox return Error 403 Forbidden - react native

Tags: react-native

I have this issue in react native when I do "react-native run-android". So, it isn't a problem of my code but it's a problem of the site "https://mapbox.bintray.com/" that returns Error 403: Forbidden? Consequently, I must just wait that they fix this server?

```
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.2.1.
Required by:
project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.1

> Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.2.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/6.2.1/mapbox-navigation-native-6.2.1.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/6.2.1/mapbox-navigation-native-6.2.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the repository reference by following these instructions:

Create a new, secret Mapbox Access Token with the scope DOWNLAODS:READ, you can read more at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/install/#configure-credentials

Add maven repository configuration to your build.gradle file, this is the point 6 of https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/install/#add-the-dependency:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      maven {
          url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
          authentication {
              basic(BasicAuthentication)
          }
          credentials {
              // Do not change the username below.
              // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
              username = "mapbox"
              // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
              password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/4533#issuecomment-880672321